# Default content for a post in one category?

Tags: functions

This is a common function that adds default text to all posts:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );
function my_editor_content( $content ) {
    $content = "default content goes here....";
    return $content;
}
```

How would this be changed to add the default content only to a post in one category?

**4/10/11 Not an exact answer, but a few choices below in my own answer**

Comment: The only time that filter runs is for new posts, at that point in time there is no relationship between that post and any taxonomy.

Comment: Is it a solution to add an intermediate page that asks for the category when creating a new post? I did a similar thing recently, I can put it in an answer if you want.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing in any case Jan, i'm curious like that... :)

Comment: @t31os: I [created a new question and answer for this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14403/force-category-choice-before-creating-new-post), because it can be useful on its own. If someone wants to go the Ajax route for this question I would be very interested too!

Comment: @t31os, That's interesting, thanks. Guess I'll need a different route. @jan, I'll look at your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is this question/answer here by Jan Fabry, which asks for the default content in the process of creating the new post:
[Force category choice before creating new post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14403/force-category-choice-before-creating-new-post)

I ended up using a Quicktag as a way of easily getting the content into a post, and because the default content happened to be html, it works as good as it can for now. But in the future there turns out to be a way to get default content into a post when that post is saved in that category, that will be good.

Quicktags function for functions.php:

```
//Custom Quicktags Function

function my_quicktags() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_quicktags',
    get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/custom-quicktags.js', array('quicktags'));
}
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_quicktags');
```

Sample Quicktags code for custom-quicktags.js, which goes in the theme folder:

```
edButtons[edButtons.length] =
new edButton('newbutton1'
,'TagButtonName'
,'html, like <div>'
,'and more </div>'
,''
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can globalize $post and check if it has the category you want:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );
function my_editor_content( $content ) {
    global $post;
    $the_one_category_id= '12'; //the category you want this to work on id
    $args= array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'ids');
    $cats = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'category',$args);
    if (in_array($the_one_category_id,$cats)){
        $content = "default content goes here....";
    }
        return $content;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like it should work fine, but I get a php error: wrong datatype for second argument, I guess meaning in in_array()

Comment: I see why, try the updated code with the array casting

Comment: The `post_category` field isn't actually used last time i checked.

Comment: Correct, i guess i'm a bit outdated on that, any changed the function, Thanks