# Add default content to post (for specific category)

Tags: posts, categories, content, customization

I'm trying to add some default content to my posts using this code in my functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );
function my_editor_content( $content ) {
$content = "My html content.";
return $content;
}
```

It works fine, but I would like to add the content to some categories only. This is tricky because the default content gets added while creating a new post, (so it is without a category). I followed this thread: 
[Force category choice before creating new post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14403/force-category-choice-before-creating-new-post)
and the author came up with a way of forcing you to choose a category before wp creates the new post, but I don't know how to edit the default content code so it is only applies to some categories?

Answer (score 1):

`default_content` runs when a post is loaded into the editor, actually. You can check for categories when the post is saved, but you'd want the [`save_post`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/save_post) hook, probably. You want to check the `$_REQUEST` global.

```
add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );
function my_editor_content( $content ) {
  global $_REQUEST;
  if (isset($_REQUEST['post_category']) && in_array($some_category_id,$_REQUEST['post_category'])) {
    $content = "My html content.";
  }
  return $content;
}
```

... assuming no syntax errors. :)

You probably also want to check if the `post_content` is empty and insert only it is.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I'm too dumb to make it work. Should I be replacing "some_category_id" with the category I want to have the default content applied to, or replace "post_category"??? I did try both, but I just get a blank space with no admin bar etc.

Am I correct in thinking this would replace the original code I was using?

Many thanks again - Excited we might get this working :)

Comment: Yes, replace `$some_category_id` with an actual category ID. Edited my code. Try the new version.

Comment: Thanks again - I edited your code like this but it still returns a blank screen - so frustrated 'cause I feel we are almost there....

add_filter( 'default_content', 'my_editor_content' );
 global $_REQUEST;
 var_dump($_REQUEST); // show you what you have to work with

 if (isset($_REQUEST['post_category'])) && in_array($product,$_REQUEST['post_category'])) {
  function my_editor_content( $content ) {
  $content = "My html content.";
 }
 return $content;
}

Comment: What you pasted into the previous comment does not match my edited code. I originally pasted something really stupid. Start over with the new code.

Comment: Good grief. I've never been here before & I don't know where to find your  "new code". Looking at these posts, all I can see is the stuff I tried / posted. I assumed you had edited your original code. If not, where is the updated version????

:O

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I edited the code I originally posted. Go all the way up to my original answer. That code is different than what I put up there at first. The original code had 'issues'. This  forum format takes some getting used to. I am only just getting a grip on it, but I am liking it.

Comment: Thanks for your patience :)

I used your updated code and no errors now, but the default content doesn't appear. Is this working for you?

Comment: It should work. I haven't had time to test it properly-- actual paying job, and such nonsense. :)

Comment: NO probs - thanks for trying anyway. I'll have another go tomorrow, but appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter to add content to a category:

```
function my_category_content ( $content ) {
    global $post;
    if ( is_single() ) {
        if ( in_category( "My Category", $post->ID ) ) {
            $content .= 'Add something';
        }
        return $content;
    } 
} 
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_category_content' );
```

This example will only display the added content on single posts though.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want default text in POST EDITOR, then use @**Milo**'s answer.

2) If you want add default content in front-end output of post,then use this code (in functions.php):

```
function add_before_content($content) { global $post;
  if ( 'page' == $post->post_type ) {return 'YOUR MESSAGE'.$content;}
  if ( 'post' == $post->post_type ) {return 'YOUR MESSAGE'.$content;}
  //etc..........
}
add_filter('the_content', add_before_content);
```