# Final Attempt - Adding default post content based on category?

Tags: post-content

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding default post content for category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69416/adding-default-post-content-for-category)

Been struggling with this for a while now, but thought I'd give it one last go.

I have some default html content (a few divs to split up the post) which I would like to automatically insert into the main post content for posts of one or maybe two categories.

I have already seen some script which will add some default content, but it is added to all new posts regardless.

I understand the main problem is that any default content is added when a post is first created (before a category is chosen). Attempting to get around this I was reading this thread about adding a drop-down menu to choose a category BEFORE the post is created.

[Force category choice before creating new post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14403/force-category-choice-before-creating-new-post)

I've tried this and it works, but I really need help with a bit of script that says:

"If the new post is in category "products" then add this html content. Otherwise don't add anything"

Hope some genius out there can help!
Cheers

Comment: duplicate of [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69416/adding-default-post-content-for-category) and [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70073/add-default-content-to-posts-in-a-specific-category). please edit your questions to add new info rather than creating duplicate questions.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but this post does contain new info

Comment: it's the same question, you should edit questions to add info, not create new questions. this isn't a support forum, the purpose of this site is an archive of information for all WordPress users, it makes the site less useful to everyone to have abandoned, unanswered questions.

Comment: OK - I give up.

Comment: Ah.. sorry, misunderstood what you were saying. I'll update yesterday's question. Apologies.