# Woocommerce Force the category choice before creating new product?

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, post-editor

How can I force the user to first choose a category product before continuing to the editor when creating a new product?

I found a successful solution but it is working for posts not products. [Force category choice before creating new post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14403/force-category-choice-before-creating-new-post)

What I did:
I changed the following code :

```
  $post_type = 'post';
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) ) {
        $post_type = $_REQUEST['post_type'];
    }

    // Only do this for posts
    if ( 'post' != $post_type ) {
        return;
    }
```

To

```
$post_type = 'product';
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) ) {
    $post_type = $_REQUEST['post_type'];
}

// Only do this for products
if ( 'product' != $post_type ) {
    return;
}
```

It worked, But it Still listing post categories not product categories.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by simply specifying the taxonomy you want to display.

```
$dropdown = wp_dropdown_categories( 
array(
    'name' => 'category_id[]', 
    'hide_empty' => false, 
    'echo' => false,
    // Set taxonomy for product categories.
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
  ) );
```

*Before posting here, you should at least do some research on how this code snippet worked for 'post', you would've found your answer yourself.*

**Reference** :

- [wp_dropdown_categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)()  from WordPress codex.
- [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26354658/6552940)

Comment: Thank you so much, the product categories loaded successfully. but when I select a category and press Continue, I found that the selected category isn't checked !!!

Comment: You will need to use the [get_default_post_to_edit](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_default_post_to_edit) to set default after the user selects the category.

Comment: Your original question was about product categories not being displayed. That is what I answered. Here at WordPress Stack Exchange we discourage 'do it for me' type of questions. You should try before you ask.

Comment: I tried for two days, but I didn't get anything. I'm not a developer.

Comment: I did add get_default_post_to_edit( 'product'); but still not working.

Comment: In that case, you should try stack overflow. You will get answers which can be used by non-developers too.

Comment: That's not how that function works, I will suggest you to try stack overflow. This site is developer centric.

Comment: I already have a question there, but no one can answer it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169000/woocommerce-force-category-choice-before-creating-new-product

Comment: Accept my answer here, since it solves your problem of categories and then ask a different question on stack overflow .

Comment: I will look into your question on SO and try to give you a better answer.