# Force category choice before creating new post

Tags: categories, post-editor

I see this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14405/144156

Code it working, but i want change category = my custom taxonomy "chuyen-muc", someone help me, thanks.

Comment: See the docs for wp_dropdown_categories() function, you can add a paramater there to use your taxonomy. Is that it?

Comment: @LeoGermani yeah i think so, im add: wp_dropdown_categories( array('taxonomy' => 'my_custom_taxonomy'
        'name' => 'category_id[]',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'echo' => false,
    ) );  But click Continue it not working, not choose my custom taxonomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ['save_post'](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) hook to programmatically enteract with your new post when it is created, then use the `wp_set_post_terms()` [function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_post_terms) to assign your term,

```
add_action('save_post','set_post_default_category', 10,3);
function set_post_default_category($post_id, $post, $update){
  if($update) return; //only want to set if this is a new post!
  if('post' !== $post->post_type) return;  //only set for post_type = post!
  $term = get_term_by('slug', 'my-custom-term', 'category');//get the default term using the slug, its more portable!
  wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $term->term_id, 'category', true );
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i just want know how change code in link, from "choose category" to "choose my custom category"  before creating new post!

Comment: you want to change the label in the editor page?